# scraping Json with python 3

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, scrape

Here is the scirpt:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests
import json
from lxml import html
from pprint import pprint

import re


def get_data():

    url = 'https://sports.bovada.lv//baseball/mlb/game-lines-market-group'
    r = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36"})
    html_bytes = r.text
    soup = bs4(html_bytes, 'lxml')

    # res = soup.findAll('script') # find all scripts..

    pattern = re.compile(r"swc_market_lists\s+=\s+(\{.*?\})")
    script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)

    return script.text[23:]

test1 = get_data()

data = json.loads(test1)


for item1 in data['items']:
    data1 = item1['itemList']['items']
    for item2 in data1:
        pitch_a = item2['opponentAName']
        pitch_b = item2['opponentBName']
##            group = item2['displayGroups']
##            for item3 in group:
##                new_il = item3['itemList']
##                for item4 in new_il:
##                    market = item4['description']                  
##                    oc = item4['outcomes']
        print(pitch_a,pitch_b)


##for items in data['items']:
##    pos = items['itemList']['items']
##    for item in pos:
##        work = item['competitors']
##        pitcher_a = item['opponentAName']
##        pitcher_b = item['opponentBName']
##        group = item['displayGroups']
##        for item, item2 in zip(work,group):
##            team = item['abbreviation']
##            place = item['type']
##            il2 = item2['itemList']
##            for item in il2:
##                ml = item['description']

##            print(team,place,pitcher_a,pitcher_b,ml)
```

I have been trying to scrape

`team abbrev` = `['items']['itemList']['items']['competitors']['abbreviation']`

`home_away` = `['items']['itemList']['items']['competitors']['type']`

`team pitcher home` = `['items']['itemList']['items']['opponentAName']`

`team pitcher away` = `['items']['itemList']['items']['opponentBName']`

`moneyline american odds` = `['items']['itemList']['items']['displayGroups']['itemList']['outcomes']['price']['american']`

`Total runs` = `['items']['itemList']['items']['displayGroups']['itemList']['outcomes']['price']['handicap']`

Part of the `Json` `pprinted`:

```
[{'baseLink': '/baseball/mlb/game-lines-market-group',
  'defaultType': True,
  'description': 'Game Lines',
  'id': '136',
  'itemList': {'items': [{'LIVE': True,
                          'atmosphereLink': '/api/atmosphere/eventNotification/events/A/3149961',
                          'awayTeamFirst': True,
                          'baseLink': '/baseball/mlb/minnesota-twins-los-angeles-angels-201805112207',
                          'competitionId': '24736',
                          'competitors': [{'abbreviation': 'LAA',
                                           'description': 'Los Angeles Angels',
                                           'id': '3149961-1642',
                                           'rotationNumber': '978',
                                           'shortName': 'Angels',
                                           'type': 'HOME'},
                                          {'abbreviation': 'MIN',
                                           'description': 'Minnesota Twins',
                                           'id': '3149961-9990',
                                           'rotationNumber': '977',
                                           'shortName': 'Twins',
                                           'type': 'AWAY'}],
                          'denySameGame': 'NO',
                          'description': 'Minnesota Twins @ Los Angeles Angels',
                          'displayGroups': [{'baseLink': '/baseball/mlb/game-lines-market-group',
                                             'defaultType': True,
                                             'description': 'Game Lines',
                                             'id': '136',
                                             'itemList': [{'belongsToDefault': True,
                                                           'columns': 'H2Columns',
                                                           'description': 'Moneyline',
                                                           'displayGroups': '136,A-136',
                                                           'id': '46892277',
                                                           'isInRunning': True,
                                                           'mainMarketType': 'MONEYLINE',
                                                           'mainPeriod': True,
                                                           'marketTypeGroup': 'MONEY_LINE',
                                                           'notes': '',
                                                           'outcomes': [{'competitorId': '3149961-9990',
                                                                         'description': 'Minnesota '
                                                                                        'Twins',
                                                                         'id': '211933276',
                                                                         'price': {'american': '-475',
                                                                                   'decimal': '1.210526',
                                                                                   'fractional': '4/19',
                                                                                   'id': '1033002124',
                                                                                   'outcomeId': '211933276'},
                                                                         'status': 'OPEN',
                                                                         'type': 'A'},
                                                                        {'competitorId': '3149961-1642',
                                                                         'description': 'Los '
                                                                                        'Angeles '
                                                                                        'Angels',
                                                                         'id': '211933277',
                                                                         'price': {'american': '+310',
                                                                                   'decimal': '4.100',
                                                                                   'fractional': '31/10',
                                                                                   'id': '1033005679',
                                                                                   'outcomeId': '211933277'},
                                                                         'status': 'OPEN',
                                                                         'type': 'H'}],
                                                           'periodType': 'Live '
                                                                         'Match',
                                                           'sequence': '14',
                                                           'sportCode': 'BASE',
                                                           'status': 'OPEN',
                                                           'type': 'WW'},
                                                          {'belongsToDefault': True,
                                                           'columns': 'H2Columns',
                                                           'description': 'Runline',
                                                           'displayGroups': '136,A-136',
                                                           'id': '46892287',
                                                           'isInRunning': True,
                                                           'mainMarketType': 'SPREAD',
                                                           'mainPeriod': True,
                                                           'marketTypeGroup': 'SPREAD',
                                                           'notes': '',
                                                           'outcomes': [{'competitorId': '3149961-9990',
                                                                         'description': 'Minnesota '
                                                                                        'Twins',
                                                                         'id': '211933278',
                                                                         'price': {'american': '+800',
                                                                                   'decimal': '9.00',
                                                                                   'fractional': '8/1',
                                                                                   'handicap': '-1.5',
                                                                                   'id': '1033005677',
                                                                                   'outcomeId': '211933278'},
                                                                         'status': 'OPEN',
                                                                         'type': 'A'},
                                                                        {'competitorId': '3149961-1642',
                                                                         'description': 'Los '
                                                                                        'Angeles '
                                                                                        'Angels',
                                                                         'id': '211933279',
                                                                         'price': {'american': '-2000',
                                                                                   'decimal': '1.050',
                                                                                   'fractional': '1/20',
                                                                                   'handicap': '1.5',
                                                                                   'id': '1033005678',
                                                                                   'outcomeId': '211933279'},
                                                                         'status': 'OPEN',
                                                                         'type': 'H'}],
                                                           'periodType': 'Live '
                                                                         'Match',
                                                           'sequence': '14',
                                                           'sportCode': 'BASE',
                                                           'status': 'OPEN',
                                                           'type': 'SPR'}],
                                             'link': '/baseball/mlb/game-lines-market-group'}],
                          'feedCode': '13625145',
                          'id': '3149961',
                          'link': '/baseball/mlb/minnesota-twins-los-angeles-angels-201805112207',
                          'notes': '',
                          'numMarkets': 2,
                          'opponentAId': '214704',
                          'opponentAName': 'Tyler Skaggs (L)',
                          'opponentBId': '215550',
                          'opponentBName': 'Lance Lynn (R)',
                          'sport': 'BASE',
                          'startTime': 1526090820000,
                          'status': 'O',
                          'type': 'MLB'},
```

There are a few different loops I had started in the script above but either of them are working out the way I would like.

away team | away moneyline | away pitcher | Total Runs | and repeat for Home Team is what I would like it to be eventually. I can write to `csv` once it is parsed the proper way.

Thank you for the fresh set of eyes, I've been working on this for the better part of a day trying to figure out the best way to access the content I would like. If `Json` is not the best way and `bs4` works better I would love to hear your opinion

Comment: To start with, `data` is a list of dicts, so `data['items']` isn't going to do anything; you need a top-level `for thing in data:` first.

Comment: Meanwhile, if you use meaningless names like `for item2 in data1`, it's very hard to keep track of where you are in the structure. Name the variables the obvious way: the list named `['itemList']['items']` should be something like `items`, not `data1`.

Comment: Finally, just trying to write the code and run it and then try again rarely works out.. You need to either run the code in a debugger, or add `print` calls to see what you have at each step, or break the pieces out into separate functions that you can call separately with smaller inputs, or something else to understand what's happening in your code, or you will never get it working.

Comment: Keep in mind, this data doesn't translate into a CSV very well. What external system do you need that requires CSV that cannot parse JSON?

Comment: @cricket_007 I will be importing into excel with legacy text/csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple answer to your problem. Scraping data requires you to carefully assess the data you are dealing with, work out where the parts you want to extract are located and figure out how to effectively store the data you extract.

Try printing the data in your loops to visualise what is happening in your code (or try debugging). From there its easy to figure out it if you're iterating over what you expect. Look for patterns throughout the input data to help organise the data you extract.

To help yourself, you should give your variables descriptive names, separate your code into logical chunks and add comments when it starts to get complicated.

Here's some working code, but I encourage you to try what I told you above, then if you're still stuck look below for guidance.

```
output = {}
root = data['items'][0]

for game_line in root['itemList']['items']:
    # Create a temporary dict to store the data for this gameline
    team_data = {}

    # Get competitors
    competitors = game_line['competitors']
    for team in competitors:
        team_type = team['type'] # either HOME or AWAY
        # Create a new dict to store data for each team 
        team_data[team_type] = {}
        team_data[team_type]['abbreviation'] = team['abbreviation']
        team_data[team_type]['name'] = team['description']


    # Get MoneyLine and Total Runs
    for item in game_line['displayGroups'][0]['itemList']:
        for outcome in item['outcomes']:
            team_type = outcome['type'] # either A or H
            team_type = 'HOME' if team_type == 'H' else 'AWAY'

            if item['mainMarketType'] == 'MONEYLINE':
                team_data[team_type]['moneyline'] = outcome['price']['american']
            elif item['mainMarketType'] == 'SPREAD':
                team_data[team_type]['total runs'] = outcome['price']['handicap']

    # Get the pitchers
    team_data['HOME']['pitcher'] = game_line['opponentAName']
    team_data['AWAY']['pitcher'] = game_line['opponentBName']

    # For each gameline, add the teamdata we gathered to the output dict
    output[game_line['description']] = team_data
```

This produces like:

```
{
  'Atlanta Braves @ Miami Marlins': {
    'AWAY': {
      'abbreviation': 'ATL',
      'moneyline': '-130',
      'name': 'Atlanta Braves',
      'pitcher': 'Mike Soroka (R)',
      'total runs': '-1.5'
    },
    'HOME': {
      'abbreviation': 'MIA',
      'moneyline': '+110',
      'name': 'Miami Marlins',
      'pitcher': 'Jarlin Garcia (L)',
      'total runs': '1.5'
    }
  },
  'Boston Red Sox @ Toronto Blue Jays': {
    'AWAY': {
      'abbreviation': 'BOS',
      'moneyline': '-133',
      'name': 'Boston Red Sox',
      'pitcher': 'David Price (L)',
      'total runs': '-1.5'
    },
    'HOME': {
      'abbreviation': 'TOR',
      'moneyline': '+113',
      'name': 'Toronto Blue Jays',
      'pitcher': 'Marco Estrada (R)',
      'total runs': '1.5'
    }
  },

}
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking that down for me, I was definitely going about that all wrong. I will go through and edit the script and play around a bit to learn. Would it be possible for you to edit your above script to export to csv? I am not familiar in exporting this script in the manner you have parsed it. If not that’s ok, that was not part of the original question and I will mark this as the answer regardless! Thank you again for going through and teaching me the proper way of scraping!

Comment: When I `print(team_data)` I can see my new dictionary. Now do I `loop` through `team_data` and create `variables` for the ones I would like to export to `csv`? I tried looping through but I am getting `string indices must be integers`..